# How to Install Ubuntu without USB or a disc

Tags: usb, system-installation, lubuntu, debian

Is there a way to install Lubuntu 14.04 on a laptop with no boot from usb capability, a broken disc drive and running Debian right now and the only way of transferring data to it being usb flash drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several options for this scenario here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Server and network installations

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a network installation available for Ubuntu, not 100% sure about LUbuntu.

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You may have to install Ubuntu with the network installer, then install the Lubuntu Desktop. I believe the command is sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop    not 100% on that though,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows on the laptop right now, you could use WUBI to install Ubuntu, then open a terminal or go to a TTY and enter,

`sudo apt-get remove account-plugin-aim account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr account-plugin-google account-plugin-icons account-plugin-identica account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut account-plugin-twitter account-plugin-windows-live account-plugin-yahoo acpi-support acpid activity-log-manager-common activity-log-manager-control-center adium-theme-ubuntu aisleriot apg app-install-data-partner appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt apt-xapian-index apturl apturl-common avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon bamfdaemon baobab binutils bluez-alsa bluez-cups bluez-gstreamer branding-ubuntu brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common brltty checkbox checkbox-qt compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default cryptsetup-bin cups-bsd dc dconf-tools deja-dup doc-base duplicity dvd+rw-tools empathy empathy-common eog espeak-data evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common example-content firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support folks-common fonts-kacst fonts-kacst-one fonts-khmeros-core fonts-lao fonts-lklug-sinhala fonts-opensymbol fonts-sil-abyssinica fonts-sil-padauk fonts-takao-pgothic fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-tibetan-machine fonts-tlwg-garuda fonts-tlwg-kinnari fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-norasi fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-sawasdee fonts-tlwg-typewriter fonts-tlwg-typist fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-umpush fonts-tlwg-waree foomatic-db-engine freerdp-x11 gcalctool gcc gcc-4.7 gedit gedit-common geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10 gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-indicate-0.7 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-syncmenu-0.1 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 gir1.2-unity-5.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-bluetooth gnome-contacts gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-signon gnome-desktop3-data gnome-font-viewer gnome-games-data gnome-mahjongg gnome-media gnome-menus gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnomine growisofs gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-x gtk2-engines-murrine guile-1.8-libs gvfs-bin gwibber gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter hplip hplip-data hwdata ibus-gtk3 ibus-pinyin ibus-pinyin-db-android ibus-pinyin-db-open-phrase ibus-table indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound intel-gpu-tools kerneloops-daemon landscape-client-ui-install laptop-detect libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt1 libart-2.0-2 libasound2-plugins libatk-adaptor libatk-adaptor-data libavahi-core7 libavahi-gobject0 libbamf3-0 libboost-date-time1.49.0 libbrasero-media3-1 libbrlapi0.5 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcamel-1.2-40 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcanberra0 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcmis-0.2-2 libcogl-common libcogl-pango0 libcogl9 libcompizconfig0 libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl libcryptsetup4 libcurl3-nss libdaemon0 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdecoration0 libdee-1.0-4 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdotconf1.0 libebackend-1.2-5 libebook-1.2-14 libecal-1.2-15 libedata-book-1.2-15 libedata-cal-1.2-18 libedataserver-1.2-17 libespeak1 libexempi3 libexiv2-12 libexttextcat-1.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfile-copy-recursive-perl libfolks-eds25 libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp1 libgail-common libgail18 libgdata-common libgdata13 libgeoclue0 libgexiv2-1 libglew1.8 libglewmx1.8 libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-4 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-menu2 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0 libgoa-1.0-common libgomp1 libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtkspell-3-0 libgweather-3-1 libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk3 libgwibber3 libhpmud0 libhyphen0 libical0 libido3-0.1-0 libindicate5 libitm1 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjs-jquery liblcms1 liblouis-data liblouis2 liblua5.1-0 liblvm2app2.2 libmessaging-menu0 libmetacity-private0a libmission-control-plugins0 libmng1 libmusicbrainz5-0 libmx-1.0-2 libmx-bin libmx-common libmysqlclient18 libmythes-1.2-0 libnotify-bin libnss-mdns libnux-3.0-0 libnux-3.0-common liboauth0 libopencc1 libpackagekit-glib2-14 libpam-freerdp libpam-gnome-keyring libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libprotobuf7 libprotoc7 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libpulsedsp libpython3.2 libqjson0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtassistantclient4 libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libquadmath0 libquvi-scripts libquvi7 libraw5 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-presentation-minimizer libreoffice-presenter-console libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer librest-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core6 librsync1 libsane-hpaio libsensors4 libsgutils2-2 libsignon-extension1 libsignon-glib1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt1 libsnmp-base libsnmp15 libsonic0 libspeechd2 libspeexdsp1 libssh-4 libstlport4.6ldbl libsync-menu1 libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libtelepathy-farstream2 libtelepathy-logger2 libtimezonemap1 libtotem-plparser17 libtotem0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 libufe-xidgetter0 libunity-core-6.0-5 libunity-misc4 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-webapps0 libunity9 libuuid-perl libvncserver0 libwacom-common libwacom2 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwmf0.2-7-gtk libyaml-tiny-perl libyelp0 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 light-themes lightdm-remote-session-freerdp lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure linux-headers-generic-pae linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev mcp-account-manager-uoa media-player-info metacity-common mousetweaks mscompress mtools mysql-common nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome notify-osd notify-osd-icons nux-tools obexd-client onboard oneconf overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 overlay-scrollbar-gtk3 pcmciautils pinyin-database pkg-config plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo policykit-desktop-privileges pptp-linux printer-driver-c2esp printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-min12xxw printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-sag-gdi printer-driver-splix protobuf-compiler pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python-apport python-configglue python-debtagshw python-dirspec python-gconf python-gi-cairo python-gnupginterface python-gst0.10 python-httplib2 python-imaging python-lxml python-mako python-markupsafe python-oauth python-openssl python-pam python-pexpect python-piston-mini-client python-problem-report python-protobuf python-pyinotify python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel python-serial python-simplejson python-sip python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-twisted-names python-twisted-web python-ubuntu-sso-client python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uno python-xapian python-zeitgeist python-zope.interface python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-crypto python3-gi-cairo python3-httplib2 python3-louis python3-lxml python3-oauthlib python3-pyatspi2 python3-pycurl python3-speechd python3-virtkey qdbus qt-at-spi radeontool remmina remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc remote-login-service rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins rhythmbox-ubuntuone rtkit samba-common samba-common-bin sane-utils seahorse session-migration sessioninstaller sgml-base shotwell signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-plugin-password signon-ui signond sni-qt software-center software-center-aptdaemon-plugins sound-theme-freedesktop speech-dispatcher ssh-askpass-gnome syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-idle telepathy-indicator telepathy-logger telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-salut thin-client-config-agent thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu thunderbird-gnome-support toshset totem totem-common totem-mozilla totem-plugins ttf-indic-fonts-core ttf-punjabi-fonts ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-settings ubuntu-sounds ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-qt ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-wallpapers ubuntu-wallpapers-quantal ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-control-panel-qt ubuntuone-couch udisks unity unity-asset-pool unity-common unity-greeter unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-gwibber unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-shopping unity-lens-video unity-scope-gdocs unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote unity-services unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-service uno-libs3 update-inetd ure usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk vino wodim xcursor-themes xdiagnose xfonts-mathml xul-ext-ubufox xul-ext-unity xul-ext-websites-integration yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zenity zenity-common && sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal && sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -g lightdm-gtk-greeter`

This long command will remove Ubuntu and install LXDE.
For other distros see [this page](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purelubuntu).

Hope it helps!

-Jack

Answer (score 0):

If you have an extra partition, you could "burn" the installer to that partition and set it as the active partition. Then reboot and boot from it. You may also have to resort to a bit of trickery if you need to create a separate partition: resize the filesystem and its containing partition. I've had some various scenarios myself where I had neither USB boot, nor a disc drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the hard drive to another laptop or computer to install then put the hard drive back into the original laptop. Admittedly a less than perfect option but it will work. I keep a couple of old hard drives with Lubuntu on them for testing any computers I pick up and because of the way Linux/Unix loads drivers, they usually boot without problem on all sorts of hardware.